# how to resolve cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I am using dagger and when I try to inject gson I get the following error

```
 e: /Users/rb/Documents/x_projects/xxx-android-app/app/src/main/java/com/xx/xxx/injection/components/AppComponent.java:44: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.google.gson.Gson cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
public interface AppComponent {
       ^
      com.google.gson.Gson is injected at
          com.xxx.xx.fragments.fueller.fo.FODF.gson
      com.xxx.xx.fragments.fueller.fo.FODF is injected at
          com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent.inject(com.xx.xxx.fragments.fueller.fo.FODF) [com.xx.xxx.injection.components.AppComponent → com.xxx.xx.injection.components.ActivityComponent]
```

AppComponent

```
    @PerApp
@Component(modules = {
        AppModule.class
})
```

AppModule has the GSON

```
@Provides
@PerApp
@Named("default")
public Gson provideGsonDefault() {
    return createGsonBuilder(true)
            .create();
}
```

This is how I use this in the FODF.kt

```
 @Inject
    @Named("default")
    lateinit var gson: Gson
```

can you please suggest what is it that I am doing wrong please

EDIT - anything wrong in this function when converting from java to kotlin through IDE -

error:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Failed to generate expression: KtBlockExpression

private val fCompleteEHCheck = label@ View.OnClickListener { v: View? ->
    if (presenter!!.hasOpenInopIncidents()) {
        appDialogHelper!!.showCannotProceedWithServiceOrderDialog()
        return@label
    }
    if (!hasFlowMeterFinishedUpdating()) {
        showErrorMessage(getString(R.string.fuel_order_totalizer_updating))
        return@label
    }
    if (!presenter!!.isDeliveryComplete()) {
        showErrorMessage("DELIVERY NOT COMPLETE")
        return@label
    }
    if (!totalizerSenseCheckHandled && presenter!!.checkAndUpdateTotalizers()) {
        totalizerSenseCheckHandled = true
        return@label
    }
    val qualityControlChecks = getQCChecksForMilestoneAndOtherUncompleted(QualityControlMilestone.F_ENDED)
    if (null != qualityControlChecks && !qualityControlChecks.isEmpty()) {
        showQualityControlDialogs(qualityControlChecks, 0, Runnable { proceedfCompleteEHCheck() })
    } else {
        proceedfCompleteEHCheck()
    }
}
```

thanks
R

Comment: what version of dagger are you using? Could be `@field:Named("default")` syntax, but in dagger 2.30.1 it shouldn't be required.

Comment: I am using 2.22.1 implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.22.1"

Comment: ok - so either update to `2.30.1` or try `@field:Named("default")` syntax using `2.22.1`

Comment: sure doing that now thank you

Comment: once I changed that it gave me this error `org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Failed to generate expression: KtBlockExpression`

Comment: IDE does not give me anymore detail.

Comment: just to give a context, what I am doing is converting a java file to kotlin

Comment: via the ide or manually?

Comment: I did through IDE and then i corrected the failures manually

Comment: I suspect the orginal problem you posted is fixed and now this is new and unrelated to the questions dagger issue - it just got further in compilation.  Either that or try the second option out of:  library update or syntax change using 2.22.1 mentioned

Comment: yes that is true for sure it is unrelated to dagger, thank you for help with dagger issue. just if you can suggest i have edited my question with the new error

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-35878 - workaround here or update koltin to `1.4.21`

Comment: i also looked at the exact same link but from my code i could not figure out which part should be changed

Comment: changed it to View.OnClickListener label@  and trying now

Comment: if you're not using kotlin `1.4.21` I suggest you update - the link suggests its fixed in `1.4.0` and affected versions were only `1.3.21` and `1.3.61`

Comment: making that change worked, thank you so much for your help